# How can I use spotDL inside python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify

I know that spotDL is a command-line application built in python, but is there any way to use it inside a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer: Yes

### Long answer: *Yes*

You see, spotDL is a command-line application, and requires the use of command-line arguments. In python, there isn't a way (as of I know) to set these arguments.

I believe you are asking on how to use an import and use a function directly such as `spotdl.download(spotifylink)`, however, the application is only designed for command-line use. So lets do that then!

### How?

Well, we can use the `subprocess` module to launch up spotdl via the python executable.

```py
import subprocess
import sys # for sys.executable (The file path of the currently using python)
from spotdl import __main__ as spotdl # To get the location of spotdl

spotifylink = "Whatever you want to download"
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, spotdl.__file__, spotifylink])
```

Edit: There is a better way to do it (Requires [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube))

```py
from spotdl import __main__ as start # To initialize
from spotdl.search.songObj import SongObj
from pytube import YouTube

spotifylink = "Whatever you want to download"
song = SongObj.from_url(spotifylink)
url = song.get_youtube_link() # Yay you have a youtube link!
yt = YouTube(url)
yts = yt.steams.get_audio_only()
fname = yts.download()

print(f"Downloaded to {fname}")
```

Comment: this was working great for me on my old laptop but it died.  I cannot remember how I got the spotdl to work in spyder.  It no longer works on my new comp.  i get this error from spotdl.command_line.core import Spotdl

args = {
    "no_encode": True,
}

with Spotdl(args) as spotdl_handler:
    spotdl_handler.download_track("https://open.spotify.com/track/2lfPecqFbH8X4lHSpTxt8l")
    print("Downloading 2nd track.")
    spotdl_handler.download_track("ncs spectre")
    print("Downloading from file.")
    spotdl_handler.download_tracks_from_file("file_full_of_tracks.txt")

Answer (score 1):

You could use os.popen like this:

```
import os
os.popen("spotdl https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXcBWIGoYBM5M")
```

Or os.system:

```
os.system("spotdl https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXcBWIGoYBM5M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually **spotDL** has got an **API** and here's the [DOCS](https://spotdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

That's a basic example on what can you do based from one of the given [examples](https://spotdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#spotdl.command_line.core.Spotdl).

```
from spotdl.command_line.core import Spotdl

args = {
    "no_encode": True,
}

with Spotdl(args) as spotdl_handler:
    spotdl_handler.download_track("https://open.spotify.com/track/2lfPecqFbH8X4lHSpTxt8l")
    print("Downloading 2nd track.")
    spotdl_handler.download_track("ncs spectre")
    print("Downloading from file.")
    spotdl_handler.download_tracks_from_file("file_full_of_tracks.txt")
```

The examples and links are for **v2** of **spotDL**, using **v3** (the common one you install with **PyPI**) will not contain these features.

You can download **v2** from [here](https://github.com/ritiek/spotify-downloader).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import spotdl
from spotdl import Spotdl

obj = Spotdl(client_id="-", client_secret="", no_cache=True)
song_objs = obj.search(["song link"])
print(song_objs)
obj.download_songs(song_objs)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.